# In swift, how to make function to return querysnapshot from Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In swift, how can I return a the `querySnapshot` in this code:

```
  func read(){
    reference(to: .users).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The above code reads the data from firebase and prints the data out in the else statement. I want to call the `read()` function from a view controller and `read()` should return the `querySnaphot!.documents`. How can I do this if I do:

```
func read() -> QuerySnaphot{
...
return querySnapshot!.documents
```

It gives me an error that it returns a non void value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

You cannot return a value inside the clouser. Instead of it you can use completion handlers.

```
 func read(_ completion:@escaping(_ querySnapshot:[QueryDocumentSnapshot])->Void){
   reference(to: .users).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {

            if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents{
                completion(documents)
            }
        }

    }
```

**Usage:**

```
read { (documents) in

    for document in documents{

          print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
     }
}
```